# Must have const value in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this code:

```
std::string name = "kingfisher";
char node_name[name.size()+1];
strcpy(node_name,name.c_str());
node_name[name.size()] = '\0';
```

It worked well in DevC++, but in Visual C++, i got a problem named "name.size() must be constant value"! How to solve the problem? I know that i have to use a const value in declaration of `node_name`, but sometimes (like the case above) i cant! thanks!

Comment: Why don't you make `node_name` also `std::string` ?

Comment: What are you doing with `node_name` after you do this? Chances are this can all be avoided, but it's hard to say how without knowing what you're doing with `node_name`.

Comment: May I suggest to you that you get used to compiling on maximum warning levels? One of them would alert you while you're on GCC in DevC++ that it's not right, and when you're finished, you can be confident that it should work on any standard-conforming compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char node_name[name.size()+1];
```

As the value of `name.size()` is not known at compile time,  in the above declaration,`node_name` is variable length array (VLA) which is not allowed in ISO C++.

In DevC++, it compiles and works, because it provides VLA feature as extension, which is enabled in your compilation configuration.

Use `std::string`, or `char *` along with `new[]/delete[]`, whatever suits your need.

In your particular case, i.e if you know the string-literal already, then you could write this:

```
char node_name[] = "kingfisher"; //this works great!
```

However, if the string value isn't known and you want to copy it from somewhere, then do this:

```
char *node_name = new char[name.size()+1];
std::strncpy(node_name, name.c_str(), name.size()+1); //use strncpy

//work with node_name

//must deallocate the memory
 delete []node_name; //not `delete node_name;`
```

Use `std::strncpy` instead of `std::strcpy`, as the former takes the buffer-size also as third argument, as shown above, and the latter doesn't (which is unsafe usually; not in this case though).

Comment: why in DevC++, it's not a problem!

Comment: @Kingfisher: because DevC++ uses gcc, which doesn't follow the C++ standard in this respect.

Comment: @Kingfisher: You are using in the compiler specific extension (gcc?) in DevC++.

Comment: @Kingfisher: Edit my post. See it.

Comment: Thanks, maybe using `char*` or `string` is the best solution!

Answer (score 3):

Variable-length arrays are not part of standard C++. You need to give the size at compile time. `name.size()` will occur at runtime. A comment should suffice to explain the magic number, or a constant.

```
char node_name[11]; //length of "kingfisher" + null
```

If you don't know the length of the string at compile time (but you do in your example), you can use a dynamic array, as explained quite well in Nawaz's answer.

Comment: I know it, but i want to use node_name[name.size()+1] because i move my program from DevC++ to VSC++! Any other suggestion?!

Comment: @Kingfisher, The only way, without compiler extensions, is to dynamically allocate the memory at runtime via one of the methods mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: @Kingfisher: I wonder why you need a `char` array at all. Your code snippet is already using `std::string`. Are you calling some API that requires a `char*`?

Comment: @Blastfurnace, That's the only thing I can think of where you would need one. In that case, it makes more sense to do it dynamically, too.

Comment: @chris: Or just pass `name.c_str()` assuming read-only access is okay.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, As long as it isn't actually a `char *`, like you said. There are times when they write to it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many choices:

```
std::string name = "kingfisher";
char* node_name = alloca(name.size() + 1);
strcpy(node_name, name.c_str());
// no need to explicitly set the '\0' - strcpy copies it too
...OR...
char* node_name = new char[name.size() + 1];
strcpy(node_name, name.c_str());
...OR...
char* node_name = strdup(name.c_str());  // allocate on malloc/free/realloc "C" heap
...OR...
std::vector<char> node_name(name.data(), name.data() + name.size()); // sans '\0'
...OR...
std::vector<char> node_name(name.c_str(), name.c_str() + name.size() + 1); // with '\0'
...OR...
std::string node_name = node;  // do something with node_name.c_str() / .data() etc.
```

Note: despite Ernest's "Don't use malloc() in C++, use new[]" comment on Stefan's deleted answer, it can be necessary - for example, when passing pointers to C code that may realloc or free the memory.

Answer (score 0):

An array whose size is determined at runtime is called a *variable-length array* or *VLA*. VLAs are a feature in C99. Some C++ compilers support them as an extension, and some do not; sounds like your version of Visual C++ does not.

You could always allocate `node_name` dynamically with `new`, rather than on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

My first approach would be to look at what you are using the array for and ask if there is a better way of doing it.

If you really need the array, I'd suggest a vector: which is dynamically sizeable but doesn't need to be deleted.

```
    std::string name = "kingfisher";
    std::vector<char> name_buff(name.begin(), name.end());
    name_buff.push_back(0);  // nul-terminate
    char *node_name = &name_buff[0];
    // ...
```